# parsing code into components

Tags: parsing, parser-generator

I need to parse some code and convert it to components because I want to make some stats about the code like number of code lines , position of condition statements and so on .

Is there any tool that I can use to fulfill that ?

Comment: It's a bit vague, IMO. Could you explain something about the language you're going to parse? Could you tell in what language you're going to do the parsing? Could you tell a bit more about the "stats" you're trying to get? What is a line of code (does it end with `\n` or with `;`)? What exactly is the _"position of condition statements"_?

Comment: If all he wants are some rough statistics, a Perl script that reads/count lines ("position of condition statements") with some ugly regexes should come close.

Comment: I'm not sure what is not clear in the question ?? 
I have code , and I need to parse it , convert it for example to XML structure then I can make some stats on it , that's all !!!

Comment: @Mohammed Well, _"some code"_ and _"and so on"_ aren't particularly specific. Parsing Perl is a _lot_ harder than many other languages for example, so that's why I asked _what_ language you're going to parse. But it seems you've found your answer already: best of luck.

Comment: @BartKiers
You are right regarding the general terms I'm using .
I will be more specific next time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is a nice tool that works with many languages, has good documentation and many sample grammars for languages included.

You can also go old-school and use Yacc and Lex (or the GNU versions Bison and Flex), which has pretty good [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) on generating parsers, as well as the classic [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

It might be overkill, however, and you might just want to use [Ruby](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) or even [Javascript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jison-build-parsers-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you very much , Antlr is what I'm searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

You mention two distinct tasks:

- refactor code into modular components
- Run static code analysis to get code metrics.

I recommend:

- Resharper, as the top code refactoring tool out there (assuming you're a .NET guy)
- NCover and NDepend for static code analysis. You get #line of code, cyclomatic complexity, abstractness vs instability diagrams.. all of the cool stuff.

Comment: Looking at the OP's posting history, he's not a NET guy.

Comment: Yes.. I see. Unfortunately not every body clearly defines the parameter of their questions. Therefore, some answers are bound to be off target..

Comment: Agreed. That's why, IMO, it's better to ask for clarification before jumping in and answering a question that is too open for speculation.